# Should this puzzle question on SO have been migrated to code-golf rather than closed?

Tags: discussion, migration

I noticed that [hello world in C without semicolons and without IF/WHILE/FOR statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147836/hello-world-in-c-without-semicolons-and-without-if-while-for-statements) was closed yesterday.  I agree with the closure--for a long time my highest voted answer was on that silly puzzle.

However, I think with it deleted it will ultimately be asked again if it doesn't show up in search engines.  The idea of the puzzle is not uncommon.

Should it have been migrated to code-golf instead?

Comment: For the record it wasn't closed yesterday, it was closed May 23.  It was *deleted* yesterday.

Comment: It seems strange to argue to undelete a post because if we don't, someone else will post it. That's debatable. But if we don't delete it, the existing one *definitely* still exists.

Comment: I don't think that question should be deleted. At best, it should be closed as "too localized" due to the arbitrary restrictions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The big impediment to that questions on CodeGolf.SE (where I am a pro-tem mod) is that we generally look for questions with [*"An objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win"*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), and while it is not written out, that kind of implies that "can you do this at all?" questions are not a very good fit; if only because in the event that there are *two or more* ways to do it, how do you sort out which one is *better*?

Answer (score 10):

Migrating questions older than 60 days is not possible anymore, not even for moderators. Stack Exchange staff has that capability, but migrating those old questions is generally a source of problems.

Having the question asked again on Code Golf is fine. If it is an acceptable question for that site, it will stay open.

Comment: This is completely true, but it's worth noting that the ban on migrating old posts was implemented very recently.

Comment: I know, but Ben Jackson is asking for the migration now that is not anymore possible. `:)`

Comment: I wasn't criticizing you, just adding info for other passersby. The reason I started my comment with "this is completely true" was to prevent you from thinking I that I thought you'd done anything wrong.

Comment: I apologize. I read that as meaning the question could have been migrated earlier (when it was not 60 days old). I didn't take it as criticizing. I was just confused by that _but_.

Comment: Ah, the magic of trying to communicate exclusively through text. No worries.

Answer (score 3):

We must be very cautious when migrating questions to SE sites, because the users of the destination SE site don't want to receive questions not perfectly relevant. For the record, the migration path to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ was removed exactly because it was a source of too much "garbage".

Personally, as someone who don't play Code Golf, I wouldn't take the risk to send them something that maybe they wouldn't welcome.

And different SE sites not only accept different kind of questions but also provide different kind of answers, which may not be what the asker wanted. The question here seemed to be *"Is it possible to do it ?"* which doesn't seem to me the typical Code Golf challenge.

Maybe this question could have been salvaged by a passing Code Golf user but I don't think SO users have to know the FAQ and usages of all SE sites. Our job was to close this question clearly out of SO's field. Salvaging it is secondary.

Comment: While this is generally true, since the question is so old (see other answers) it couldn't be migrated even if you wanted to.

Comment: I don't answer on "should it be migrated now ?" but "Should this puzzle question on SO have been migrated to code-golf rather than closed?"

Comment: And yet that's the question that the OP asked.  As I said, this isn't wrong, and it's even worth mentioning, but it should be mentioned *in addition to* mentioning that migrating this particular question is impossible, not just undesirable.

Comment: The migration path to Programmers was removed largely because two other sites had a higher volume of mod-driven migrations going to them. The fact that a percentage of migrations to Prog.SE was wrong was more or less tangential.